# How to overload * op to multiply constant and single dim array member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So, I have a rather specific question that I can't for the life of me find referenced on the internet anywhere.

I want to know how to overload the * operator so that I can multiply  between a constant and a part of an array.

My code, at least the bit that's relavent, if more is needed I can post:

```
    licenseCount licenseCount::operator * (const licenseCount& u) const
    {
        return(this->fxdx*u.fxdx, this->y_array*u.y_array);
    }

    int licenseCount::calc_vol(double z, char *argv[])
    {
        int area;
        std::string y_array[9];

        std::ifstream y_data;

        y_data.open( argv[1] );

        if(y_data.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "Can't open file!\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=9;i++)
            {
                int temp;
                y_data >> y_array[i];
                std::cout << y_array[i] << '\n';

                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                    temp = 2 * y_array[i];
                    area += fxdx * temp;
                }
                else if(i = 0)
                {
                   area += fxdx * y_array[i];
                }
                else
                {   
                   temp = 4 * y_array[i];
                   area += fxdx * temp;
                }
                std::cout << area;
            }

        vol = area * depth;

        return vol;
    }
```

My errors:

```
licenseCount.cpp:62: error: 'const class licenseCount' has no member named 'y_array'
licenseCount.cpp:62: error: 'const class licenseCount' has no member named 'y_array'
licenseCount.cpp: In member function `int licenseCount::calc_vol(double, char**)':
licenseCount.cpp:90: error: no match for 'operator*' in '2 * y_array[i]'
licenseCount.cpp:91: warning: converting to `int' from `double'
licenseCount.cpp:95: error: no match for 'operator*' in '((licenseCount*)this)-licenseCount::fxdx * y_array[i]'
licenseCount.cpp:98: error: no match for 'operator*' in '4 * y_array[i]'
licenseCount.cpp:99: warning: converting to `int' from `double'
licenseCount.cpp:111: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
licenseCount.cpp:113: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

I have searched far and wide on the internet, perhaps my search terms were faulty, but I used every combination of words I could think of to attempt to find an answer. /sigh

Heads up, this IS homework, but your explanations/help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It appears there's no member `y_array`.

Comment: How do I declare a string within a class? It throws me all kinds of crazy when I try..

Comment: Would I have to declare it as a function? o.O If so... I'm so lost.

Comment: No, it needs to be a data member. You do seem lost and this is overly general to answer here. You should read an introductory C++ book.

Comment: Okay, great, but string isn't a data *type*, at least according to my compiler

Comment: Have you included `<string>`. Are you calling it `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access y_array, a variable which is local to calc_vol only, by a u.y_array notation, which would refer to y_array, a member of class license count, which isn't the same namespace as the y_array your code shows a declaration for.

You'd need to declare y_array as a std::string in your class licenseCount (and so on), instead of in calc_vol.  The erroneous declaration in calc_vol would mask a correct in-class member declaration of y_array.  The use later with y_array[i] would be unchanged, other than referring to the this->y_array (the "this->" would be implicit).

The use of this in licenseCount is superfluous, since class methods can refer to instance methods without "this->".